# GWT blamed RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run on on sub module(project) when launching main project

Tags: gwt, maven, requestfactory, google-plugin-eclipse, gwt-maven-plugin

`GWT 2.5.0`/`Google Plugin for Eclipse`/`m2e`/`GWT-maven-plugin 2.5.0`/`Request Factory`

I configs my project according to the GWT wiki [working with maven](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven) and it works pretty well, but has some trouble in my sub-project.

Suppose i have two project A and B, A is a standard GWT project, B is sub-project and has one GWT module, it contains some common UI widgets and some common Entity proxies and RequestFactory, A project depends on B project through Maven dependency, and also in A's Module.gwt.xml, there is an inheritance on B module.

The problem is when i try to lauching A project using GPE, it blames:

```
The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the … XXXRequestFactory type
```

where the XXXRequestFactory is in B project. I have to close project B in Eclipse, so it will not blames, this is cumbersome when i want to modify something in B project which used in A to see the changes, i have to close B then see the changes, then open B and made changes...

I wonder if there is a way to solve this problem so my life would be easier.
Thanks.

One more thing, i also use `maven-processor-plugin` and `build-helper-maven-plugin` in project B, and make sure the goals are run when i call `maven install` on B, but seems no help.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and here is the solution which fixed this issue. This answer assumes that you need to execute the GWT app in dev mode (as you mentioned you tried with gwt eclipse plugin)

1. You may already know this `RequestFactory` must validate the interfaces, domain types and proxies before execution. So you need to enable annotation processing for this which creates mapping data for server side components in addition to said validation. If this process not succeeded it will throw the error you mentioned.
2. You can enable the requestfactory validation for project B in the project properties. Go to compiler properties, enable annotation processing providing the path to `requestfactory-apt.jar`. After this when you compile the project you can see the `.apt_generated` in your project home dir containing mapping files. If you open one of them you can see generated mappings for your proxies.
3. Launch the application (project A in your case) and it should run without any errors

In Maven world you have to specify the dependency for this apt jar. In addition to this you might get compiler errors in those generated classes when doing `mvn compile`, to resolve that simply delete the content in `.apt_generated`.